# Angular 2/ Type Script classes to JSON object

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to create a class that can use to send a json object to a REST API. This is the json object that i need to send.

```
{
  "libraryName": "temp",
  "triggerName": "trigger",
  "currentVersion": "1.3",
  "createdUser": "xyz",
  "visibilityType": "private",
  "WFAllowdTeam": {
    "allowedTeam": "team1"
  },
  "WFLibraryHistory": {
    "createdDate": "2016-7-7T05:10:04.106Z",
    "modifiedDate": "2016-7-9T05:10:04.106Z"
  }
}
```

I tried creating a class like this and  tried to set the data by creating an object `this.library.WFAllowdTeam.WFAllowdTeam = 'team';`, Please find the class i created here,

```
   class WFLibraryHistory {
        public createdDate: any;
        public modifiedDate: any;
    }

    class WFAllowdTeam {
        public WFAllowdTeam: string;
    }

    export class Library {
        public libraryName: string;
        public triggerName: string;
        public currentVersion: string;
        public createdUser: string;
        public visibilityType: string;
        public libraryID: string;
        WFLibraryHistory: WFLibraryHistory;
        WFAllowdTeam: WFAllowdTeam;
    }
```

The error is,

```
platform-browser.umd.js:937 TypeError: Cannot set property 'WFAllowdTeam' of undefined
    at WFLibraryComponentAddNewWorkflow.createWorkflow (wf-library.component.new.workflow.ts:47)
    at DebugAppView._View_WFLibraryComponentAddNewWorkflow0._handle_click_61_0 (WFLibraryComponentAddNewWorkflow.ngfactory.js:488)
    at eval (core.umd.js:12718)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.umd.js:9181)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:240)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:192)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:133)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:93)
    at EventEmitter.Subject._finalNext (Subject.ts:154)
    at EventEmitter.Subject._next (Subject.ts:144)
```

Any help to overcome this issue will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate those (class) members first.

```js
export class Library {
    public libraryName: string;
    public triggerName: string;
    public currentVersion: string;
    public createdUser: string;
    public visibilityType: string;
    public libraryID: string;
    WFLibraryHistory: WFLibraryHistory;
    WFAllowdTeam: WFAllowdTeam;

    constructor() {
       this.WFLibraryHistory = new WFLibraryHistory();
       this.WFAllowdTeam = new WFAllowdTeam();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of `WFAllowdTeam` before you can modify any of its properties.

```
this.library.WFAllowdTeam = new WFAllowdTeam();
this.library.WFAllowdTeam.WFAllowdTeam = 'team';
```